# Вызов Activity через Button

Tags: android, activity

Я создал `Activity` и обработчик кнопки для перехода между двумя `Activity`. Далее хочу создать вторую кнопку, чтобы при нажатии на неё, открывалась третья `Activity`. Написал код:

```
btnEdTl1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdTl1);
btnEdTl1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Но когда нажимаю на обе кнопки, то открывается одна и та же `Activity`. Как сделать, чтобы вторая кнопка открывала другую `Activity`. 
Где-то слышал, что это можно сделать добавив код в `case`, но не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете в `setOnClickListener` параметр `this`, тоесть ссылку на этот же класс, значит вы имплементировали слушатель (`implements OnClickListener`) и реализовали метод `onClick(View v)`. Выходит, что вы поставили один и тот же слушатель нв обе кнопки.

**Один**

Вы можете установить на каждую кнопку отдельный слушатель

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ...);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ...);
```

**Два**

Вы можете просто расширить ваш единственный слушатель

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Class to = null;
    switch(v.getId)
    {
        case R.id.btn1: //кнопка с id = btn1
            to = FirstActivity.class;
            break;
        case R.id.btn2: //кнопка с id = btn2
            to = SecondActivity.class;
            break;
    }
    if(to != null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, to));
    }
}
```

Можно вместо `switch/case` использовать `if/else` (в данном случае можно. Но когда лесенка большая, лучше `switch/case`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Class to = null;
    if(v.getId())
    {
        to = FirstActivity.class;
    }
    else
    {
        to = SecondActivity.class;
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this, to));
}
```

А ещё лучше тернарный

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, v.getId() == R.id.btn1 ? FirstActivity.class : SecondActivity.class));
```

Comment: Помог второй способ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вам следует установить для каждой из кнопок свою реализацию OnClickListener'а.

```
btnEdTl1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdTl1);
btnEdTl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
    }
});

btnEdTl2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdTl2);
btnEdTl2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }
});
```